# python parquet install fails on macos with snappy and thiftpy

Tags: python, parquet

I am relatively new to python.  I need a fast IO format with modest disk requirements.  feather lacks compression, so parquet it is.  I tried to install

```
sudo pip3 install parquet
```

on macos 10.14.6, Python 3.7.4, pip 19.1.1.

the first set of errors relate to snappy.  they can be fixed with `brew install snappy` and `sudo pip3 install snappy`.  (Q: could pip3 not automatically figure out and satisfy the dependency, or at least instruct how to fix this?)

but then, I am out of luck:

```
...
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c thriftpy/transport/cybase.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/thriftpy/transport/cybase.o
thriftpy/transport/cybase.c:3127:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
    tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
               ~~~~~~  ^
thriftpy/transport/cybase.c:3128:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
    tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                        ^~~~~~~~~
                        curexc_value
...
```

Quo Vadis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parquet` package is unmaintained and outdated. To read and write Parquet files in Python, you should install `pyarrow` and use the `pyarrow.parquet` module.

When you have `pyarrow` and `pandas` installed you can also use `pandas`'s Parquet functionality with `pandas.read_parquet` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet` for convenience.

Comment: can it be removed?  I am probably not the first to stumble over parquet and fastparquet and then wonder why nothing works...

Comment: `fastparquet` should also work. Deleting packages from PyPI is though something highly discussable and probably better discussed on http://discuss.python.org

Comment: fastparquet won't work if you need 'snappy' because 'python-snappy' fails to build in MacOS