# Can't install parquet via pip nor conda on macOS "Big Sur"

Tags: python, macos, pip, parquet, miniconda

I'm trying install parquet either via pip or conda.

Command I used for pip: (for my main python install)

```
pip install parquet
```

Per comment, tried:

```
pip install parquet --no-cache-dir
```

Gives error:

```
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c thriftpy2/transport/cybase.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/cybase.o
clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11'
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

Commands I used to try it via conda:  (for my miniconda3 environment)

```
zsh
source activate opencv
conda install parquet
```

Note: Although I recently upgraded my Big Sur OS, I believe I still have the Apple Xcode command line tools installed correctly:

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

**Pip errors:**

```
Collecting parquet
  Using cached parquet-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting thriftpy2
  Using cached thriftpy2-0.4.13.tar.gz (365 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: ply<4.0,>=3.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from thriftpy2->parquet) (3.11)
Requirement already satisfied: six~=1.15 in /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.14.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from thriftpy2->parquet) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: thriftpy2
  Building wheel for thriftpy2 (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for thriftpy2 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-install-24lg9_3r/thriftpy2_b14f59c024c149e2ad765d39429fbf7c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-install-24lg9_3r/thriftpy2_b14f59c024c149e2ad765d39429fbf7c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-wheel-zoxlrw_g
       cwd: /private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-install-24lg9_3r/thriftpy2_b14f59c024c149e2ad765d39429fbf7c/
  Complete output (94 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/hook.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/thrift.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/rpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/tornado.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/http.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  copying thriftpy2/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  copying thriftpy2/transport/_ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  copying thriftpy2/transport/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  copying thriftpy2/transport/sslsocket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  copying thriftpy2/transport/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  copying thriftpy2/transport/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/apache_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/compact.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/exc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/multiplex.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/json.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
  copying thriftpy2/parser/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
  copying thriftpy2/parser/parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
  copying thriftpy2/parser/exc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
  copying thriftpy2/parser/lexer.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/memory
  copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/memory
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
  copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/framed
  copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/framed
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/client.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/processor.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/rpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/tracker.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/buffered.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/framed.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/compact.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
  running egg_info
  writing thriftpy2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to thriftpy2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to thriftpy2.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to thriftpy2.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'thriftpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'thriftpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
  copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/endian_port.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
  copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/memory
  copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/memory
  copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
  copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
  copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/framed
  copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/framed
  copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/tracking.thrift -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
  running build_ext
  building 'thriftpy2.transport.cybase' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
  creating build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c thriftpy2/transport/cybase.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/cybase.o
  clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11'
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for thriftpy2
  Running setup.py clean for thriftpy2
Failed to build thriftpy2
Installing collected packages: thriftpy2, parquet
    Running setup.py install for thriftpy2: started
    Running setup.py install for thriftpy2: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-install-24lg9_3r/thriftpy2_b14f59c024c149e2ad765d39429fbf7c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-install-24lg9_3r/thriftpy2_b14f59c024c149e2ad765d39429fbf7c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-record-m7lxkivf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/thriftpy2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-install-24lg9_3r/thriftpy2_b14f59c024c149e2ad765d39429fbf7c/
    Complete output (93 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/hook.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/thrift.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/rpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/tornado.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/http.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    copying thriftpy2/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    copying thriftpy2/transport/_ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    copying thriftpy2/transport/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    copying thriftpy2/transport/sslsocket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    copying thriftpy2/transport/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    copying thriftpy2/transport/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/apache_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/compact.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/exc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/multiplex.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/json.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
    copying thriftpy2/parser/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
    copying thriftpy2/parser/parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
    copying thriftpy2/parser/exc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
    copying thriftpy2/parser/lexer.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/parser
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/memory
    copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/memory
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
    copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/framed
    copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/framed
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/client.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/processor.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/rpc.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/tracker.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/buffered.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport/framed.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/transport
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/compact.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol/base.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/aio/protocol
    running egg_info
    writing thriftpy2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to thriftpy2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to thriftpy2.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to thriftpy2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'thriftpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'thriftpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    copying thriftpy2/transport/cybase.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    creating build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
    copying thriftpy2/protocol/cybin/endian_port.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/protocol/cybin
    copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/memory
    copying thriftpy2/transport/memory/cymemory.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/memory
    copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
    copying thriftpy2/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/buffered
    copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.c -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/framed
    copying thriftpy2/transport/framed/cyframed.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/framed
    copying thriftpy2/contrib/tracking/tracking.thrift -> build/lib.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/contrib/tracking
    running build_ext
    building 'thriftpy2.transport.cybase' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2
    creating build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c thriftpy2/transport/cybase.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/thriftpy2/transport/cybase.o
    clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11'
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-install-24lg9_3r/thriftpy2_b14f59c024c149e2ad765d39429fbf7c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-install-24lg9_3r/thriftpy2_b14f59c024c149e2ad765d39429fbf7c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/y3/rxnq666x3cq3c76ss368pdpc0000gp/T/pip-record-m7lxkivf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/thriftpy2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

**Conda Errors:**

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - parquet

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: What `clang --version` are you at? By any chance did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63972598/6382901)?

Comment: It looks like you have a yanked version cached; try `pip install parquet --no-cache-dir`. If you get another `clang` error, please add it to the question (two lines starting with `clang -Wno-unused-result ...` and `clang: error: ...` will already suffice)

Comment: However, I can build a wheel with 0.4.13, so this is probably another issue. Try removing your CLT from `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and reinstalling via `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: In general you should use [`conda activate`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#id226) instead of `source activate` now.

Comment: Hi @Jedi, clang --version gives: Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)

Comment: @hoefling I tried with --no-cache-dir, but still got errors, which I've now included in the original question above.

Comment: @hoefling I tried reinstalling the command line tools.  If I run pip with --no-cache-dir now I get a lot of "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:202:2: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
            uint8_t  ri_uuid[16];"

Comment: Try setting `export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1` followed by your `pip install parquet` command.This seems to be the same issue as in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972113/big-sur-clang-invalid-version-error-due-to-macosx-deployment-target).

Comment: Can you  try: `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0  pip install parquet`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install "parquet" in another way then you'll need Pycharm, It should be easy to install.

Open Pycharm and follow the steps:

1. Go to preferences
2. click Python Interpreter Under Project section
3. click on "+" as in image

[image]

4. Search for "parquet"

[image]

5. click install.

[image]

6. After you install the parquet it should be visible in `step 2`

---

Could Also Try `pip3 install parquet`

Please let me know if any issues.

Comment: When searching for Parquet, all I have is "fastparquet", "intake-parquet", "parquet-cpp" and "json2parquet", but no plain Parquet

Comment: Really hoping to also get this working via command line.

Comment: Strange. Even I'm using BigSur and it's visible on my Pycharm. what version of python are you using?

Comment: also try `pip3 install parquet` in your command line if you have python3 installed

Answer (score 2):

From the error it's clear that `pip` is trying to compile `parquet` on your system. This error is because `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0` is not included in the stable XCode Command Line Tools for MacOS 11. You need to install  [XCode Command Line Tools 12.3 Beta](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.3_beta/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.3_beta.dmg). After that just run `pip install` again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something wrong with xcode. Try this:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Ensure that xcode has installed from appstore and run:

```
$ sudo xcode-select --install
```

Comment: mine was ujson not parquet, but this fixed my issue when I got the same error

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
python -m pip install parquet
```

(You might want to try using *python2* or *python3* depending on which python version you're using, if you don't know you can check it with *python --version*).

Also, [parquet has been tested on python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7](https://pypi.org/project/parquet/), so if you don't have one of those versions that might be the problem

You could also try to build a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and try installing parquet in there!

Answer (score 0):

Its seem that parquet cant install it self on the system with pip
and some version of conda wont be able to run correctly with certain library

Solution:

1. reinstall pip: maybe your pip is broken some how
2. use pycharm to install your lib (include parquet)
3. clone from git and install manually if possible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not what you want or you already find it, but this answer [python parquet install fails on macos with snappy and thiftpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57682417/python-parquet-install-fails-on-macos-with-snappy-and-thiftpy) maybe help look for another way out.

> The parquet package is unmaintained and outdated. To read and write Parquet files in Python, you should install `pyarrow` and use the `pyarrow.parquet` module.